# Gremlin Concurrent Modification Exception on Neptune

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have seen many concurrent modification exceptions emerging since I changed a small Gremlin operation in a .Net setting, with Neptune as a the back-end.  I'm struggling to understand what could be causing it.

This is my new query

```
await Graph.V(itemId)
                .ActiveLinkedVertex(DbLabels.ComponentEdge)
                .OutE(DbLabels.ComponentEdge).HasNot(DbLabels.EdgeToProperty)
                .MarkToDate(_operationTime)
                .Promise(t => t.Iterate());
```

and this is my ActiveLinkedVertex extension

```
public static GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> ActiveLinkedVertex(this GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal, string edgeLabel)
{
            traversal = traversal.OutE(edgeLabel)
                .HasNot(DbLabels.EdgeToProperty)
                .InV();

            return traversal;
}
```

And here's my 'MarkToDate'

```
public static GraphTraversal<S, E> MarkToDate<S, E>(this GraphTraversal<S, E> traversal, DateTime utcUpdateTime)
{
            traversal = traversal.Property(DbLabels.EdgeToProperty, utcUpdateTime).Property(DbLabels.EdgeToTicksProperty, utcUpdateTime.Ticks);
            return traversal;
}
```

The query is getting hit in a multithreaded setting, but never on the same itemId or even itemId's parent.  Each thread is working on an isolated subgraph.

Is there anything in the internal implementation of Neptune/Gremlin that I'm missing that could cause a broad lock to be taken, for example, or is my query open to concurrent mods in some way?

**Additional Information** (edit)

The new query replaced a buggy version, that was

```
await Graph.V(itemId)
                .Out(DbLabels.ComponentEdge)
                .OutE(DbLabels.ComponentEdge)
                .MarkToDate(_operationTime)
                .Promise(t => t.Iterate());
```

This is is simplified view of what the graph is.  Everything below a group is being done on a separate thread and in-order.  There can be x-links between Vertices labelled as 'Part' in different groups, but the edges we're mutating are the Component edges between the green and purple verts at the bottom (MarkToDate on the edges)

I've read on the Neptune docs that range locks taken on neighbouring nodes can cause CMEs, but I am finding it hard to understand whether a CME is possible when mutating the edges at the bottom below, under separate Groups.  If I put back the original (bugged) update, then there are no CMEs.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code what exactly might be going on. Concurrent Modification Exceptions (CME) are generally re-triable and can happen if two (or more) threads hit more or less the same part of the graph at the same time. Can you say any more about the change you made from when it was working before? There is a parameter group setting that you can try changing (which essentially weakens the locking) but I'm hesitant to suggest that without learning a bit more about what changed. If you are able it might also be worthwhile opening a support case, but happy to try and help also.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Kelvin.  I've updated the original question with some extra information.  I have put in a retry policy for all mutating request now and that has fixed the issue, but I'd like to understand more about how it's arisen.  I have about 8 threads, each processing a 'Group' and iterating the links in a group's heirarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the updates and the diagram. I'm glad the retries worked. In general that is a good practice as it can happen and application code needs to be able to handle it. Are you able to open a support case? That might be the best way to get more insight by having a support engineer look at the specific case. As you noted, more than the exact element being mutated can get locked. I'm also going to copy my original comment into an answer so that others finding the question will see it. I'll update the answer as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I will see about a support case.  I think we're vague on the internals of what exactly can get locked and how broad locks can be, but it's good to know that locks can affect 'nearby' elements - not just the ones being modified.  Clearing that idea up helps reduce the concern that there's a bug in our code.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from the code what exactly might be going on. Concurrent Modification Exceptions (CME) are generally re-triable and can happen if two (or more) threads hit more or less the same part of the graph at the same time. Due to the way locking works, it is hard to give you a single rule about when CMEs may occur and how to avoid them, but the most common reason is when two or more threads try to mutate the same area of the database.

In general, application code should plan to catch, and handle CMEs during concurrent mutation of the graph, and in most cases a backoff/retry strategy is sufficient.